# Xcode перекомпиляция проекта в storyboard

Tags: xcode

Создал кастомный `view`

```
class ACRCircleView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }
}
```

Расположил его в `storyboard`, теперь каждый раз, когда я захожу в `storyboard` xcode постоянно пересобирает проект, что мешает работе, тк начинает тормозить. Можно ли как-то указать, что ради этого класса пересобирать проект не нужно ? его хкод может не рендерить. Есть вариант программно расположить эту вьюшку, но хотелось бы еще варианты найти, если они есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке меню выберите `Editor` и уберите галочку `Automatically Refresh Designable Views`

Ну а лучший вариант – построение UI кодом и использование Previews.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]